# Math adjustment of swipe factor

Tags: objective-c, math

I cannot figure this out. So I'm swiping a card (tinder style) and I'm capturing `swipePercent` from 0.0 to 1.0... I want the animation on the next card to happen between 0.2 and 0.4.

So I need a variable `swipePercentAdjusted` that starts at 0.0 when `swipePercent = 0.2` and then ramps up to 1.0 when `swipePercent = 0.4`.

I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
if (swipePercent >= 0.2 && swipePercent <= 0.4) {
    CGFloat swipePercentAdjusted = (swipePercent - 0.2) / 0.2;
}
```

Examples:

swipePercent is 0.2 yields 0.0
swipePercent is 0.3 yields 0.5
swipePercent is 0.4 yields 1.0

Answer (score 0):

The most brutal solution is just to remap the interval 0.2 - 0.4 to 0.0 - 1.0. (Which is similar to rmaddys solution).

```
if(swipePercent<0.2)
  return 0.0;
if(swipePercent>0.4)
  return 1.0;
return (swipePercent-0.2)/(0.4-0.2)
```

Which can be implemented in a simple function

```
double remapLinear(double low, double high, double value) {
  if(swipePercent<low)
    return 0.0;
  if(swipePercent>high)
    return 1.0;
  return (swipePercent-low)/(high-low)
}
```

However sometimes this is too abrupt. In that case you can use a cosine based transition

```
double remapSmooth(double low, double high, double value) {
  if(swipePercent<low)
    return 0.0;
  if(swipePercent>high)
    return 1.0;
  double z = (swipePercent-low)/(high-low);
  return 0.5-0.5*cos(z*PI);
}
```